# How does the MSAL authentication actually works even there is no function calling for Authentication

Tags: angular, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal, azure-authentication

I am very new to MSAL and seriously havent got an idea how the program works even after its working fine when copying and pasting the code from MSAL [wiki](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/wiki)

Here is my code blocks

In 3 pages I made my changes to accomplish MSAL.
One is in my Routing page.
Next is in App Module
and last in App component

Here is my code for these 3 pages

App Module

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppRoutingModule, RoutingComponent } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { DemoMaterialModule } from './materials-modules'
import { ForecastComponent } from './forecast/forecast.component';
import { TypeofchangeComponent } from './typeofchange/typeofchange.component';
import { ExistinginfoComponent } from './existinginfo/existinginfo.component';
import { CrMainComponent, MyCurrencyPipe, MyDatePipe } from './crmain/crmain.component';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { MatAutocompleteModule } from '@angular/material/autocomplete';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { NgSelect2Module } from 'ng-select2'
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatCheckboxModule } from '@angular/material/checkbox';
import { LoaderComponent } from './components/shared/loader/loader.component';
import { MatProgressSpinnerModule } from '@angular/material/progress-spinner';
import { LoaderService } from './services/loader.service';
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { LoaderInterceptor } from './interceptors/loader.interceptor';
import { ReviewComponent } from './review/review.component';
import  { ToastrModule } from 'ngx-toastr';
import {  MsalInterceptor, MsalModule } from '@azure/msal-angular';
import { MAT_DATE_LOCALE } from '@angular/material/core';

const isIE = window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE ') > -1 || window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Trident/') > -1;
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ForecastComponent,
    TypeofchangeComponent,
    ExistinginfoComponent,
    RoutingComponent,
    CrMainComponent,
    LoaderComponent,
    ReviewComponent,
    MyCurrencyPipe,
    MyDatePipe
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatAutocompleteModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    DemoMaterialModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    NgSelect2Module,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
    ToastrModule.forRoot(),
    MsalModule.forRoot({
      auth: {
        clientId: 'myclientid', // This is your client ID
        authority: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/mytenantid', // This is your tenant ID
        redirectUri: 'http://localhost:4200'// This is your redirect URI
       
      },
      cache: {
        cacheLocation: 'sessionStorage',
        storeAuthStateInCookie: isIE, // Set to true for Internet Explorer 11
      },
    }, {
      popUp: !isIE,
      consentScopes: [
                  'user.read',
                  'openid',
                  'apitoken/user_impersonation',
                ], 
      unprotectedResources: [],
      protectedResourceMap: [
                  [
                    'https://localhost:44331/',
                    ['apitoken/user_impersonation'],
                  ]
                  
                ], 
      extraQueryParameters: {}
    })
  ],
 providers: [
  LoaderService,
  {
    provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,useClass: MsalInterceptor, multi: true
  },
  { 
    provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: LoaderInterceptor, multi: true 
  },
  {
    provide: MAT_DATE_LOCALE, useValue: 'en-GB'
  }
],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Here is App Component

```
import { Component, Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, Subscription } from 'rxjs';

import { BroadcastService, MsalService } from '@azure/msal-angular';
import { CryptoUtils, Logger, AuthError, AuthResponse } from 'msal';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
  title = 'angular-client';  

  loggedIn : boolean;

  public userInfo: any = null;

  private subscription: Subscription;

  public isIframe: boolean;
 
  constructor(private broadcastService: BroadcastService , private authService : MsalService ) {

    this.isIframe = window !== window.parent && !window.opener;

   if(this.authService.getAccount())

    {
//console.info(JSON.stringify(this.authService.getAccount()));
      this.loggedIn = true;

    }

   else {

     this.loggedIn = false;
     //this.login();

   }
  }

  login()
  {

    const isIE = window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE ") > -1 || window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Trident/") > -1;



    if (isIE) {

      this.authService.loginRedirect();

    } else {

      this.authService.loginPopup();

    }

  }



  logout()

  {

   this.authService.logout();

  }





  ngOnInit() {


    
    this.broadcastService.subscribe("msal:loginFailure", (payload) => {
      alert(2);
      //console.log("login failure " + JSON.stringify(payload));

      this.loggedIn = false;



    });



    this.broadcastService.subscribe("msal:loginSuccess", (payload) => {
      alert(3);
      console.log("login success " + JSON.stringify(payload));

      this.loggedIn = true;
      //alert("Login Success");

    });

    this.authService.handleRedirectCallback((redirectError: AuthError, redirectResponse: AuthResponse) => {
      alert(4);
      if (redirectError) {
        console.error("Redirect error: ", redirectError);
        return;
      }

      console.log("Redirect success: ", redirectResponse);
    });
    
  }



 ngOnDestroy() {

    this.broadcastService.getMSALSubject().next(1);

    if(this.subscription) {

      this.subscription.unsubscribe();

    }

  }

  
}
```

Here is my Routing page

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { ForecastComponent } from './forecast/forecast.component';
import { ExistinginfoComponent } from './existinginfo/existinginfo.component';
import { TypeofchangeComponent } from './typeofchange/typeofchange.component';

import { dashCaseToCamelCase } from '@angular/compiler/src/util';
import { CrMainComponent  } from './crmain/crmain.component';
import { DataAccessService } from './services/data-access.service';
import { MsalGuard } from '@azure/msal-angular';



const routes: Routes = [
  {path:'forecast',canActivate: [MsalGuard],component:ForecastComponent},
  {path:'existinginfo',component:CrMainComponent},
  {path:'typeofchange',component:TypeofchangeComponent},
  {path : '',canActivate: [MsalGuard], component:CrMainComponent},
  {path : 'das',canActivate: [MsalGuard], component:CrMainComponent},
  {path : 'callback', component:CrMainComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { } 
export const RoutingComponent=[ForecastComponent,ExistinginfoComponent,TypeofchangeComponent, CrMainComponent]
```

Only thing I did is MSAL Guard in routing. Is that because the Application redirects and authenticate automatically without calling any login method??

Also sometimes I am facing a token renewal error. Not always... Sometimes.. But honestly i have no idea where to call the renew.

I was expecting a solution to renew before the token expires.. Or it really expire??

Someone please help me to figure out how the login is actually getting called and how to renew token without affecting users current work.

Also as you can see I have specified 3 alerts in app component. None is working. So those functions as well not being called. So totally confused how this is all working.

Comment: Please let me know which version angular you are using?

Comment: @SruthiJ-MSFTIdentity Mine is Angular 9. Backend is .NET core 3.0

Comment: It would be more helpful for us  If you can provide the exact error code /scenario you are facing while token renewal .so that we can guide you on the right path.

Comment: The application automatically authenticates if the user account is already login in the browser. In component level, the user is verified with below function as if the user logged in application won't ask you for login prompt

    checkoutAccount() {
    this.loggedIn = !!this.authService.getAccount();
    }

Answer (score 1):

The application automatically authenticates if the user account is already login in the browser. In component level, the user is verified with below function as if the user logged in application won't ask you for login prompt

```
checkoutAccount() {
this.loggedIn = !!this.authService.getAccount();
}
```